# Error installing eo-learn dependency lightgbm

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew

I have tried to use eolearn on macOS in the past but I ran into this problem.

I am attempting to install the package 'eolearn' from sentintelhub for a project on my Mac Mini M1.

Python: `Python 3.10.6`

Error:

```
(env) alex@Alexs-Mac-mini external-adapter % pip install lightgbm                  

Collecting lightgbm
  Using cached lightgbm-3.3.2.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in ./env/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from lightgbm) (0.37.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./env/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from lightgbm) (1.23.3)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in ./env/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from lightgbm) (1.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn!=0.22.0 in ./env/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from lightgbm) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in ./env/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scikit-learn!=0.22.0->lightgbm) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=1.0.0 in ./env/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scikit-learn!=0.22.0->lightgbm) (1.2.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: lightgbm
  Building wheel for lightgbm (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [80 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      /Users/alex/iris/external-adapter/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib
      creating build/lib/lightgbm
      copying lightgbm/callback.py -> build/lib/lightgbm
      copying lightgbm/compat.py -> build/lib/lightgbm
      copying lightgbm/plotting.py -> build/lib/lightgbm
      copying lightgbm/__init__.py -> build/lib/lightgbm
      copying lightgbm/engine.py -> build/lib/lightgbm
      copying lightgbm/dask.py -> build/lib/lightgbm
      copying lightgbm/basic.py -> build/lib/lightgbm
      copying lightgbm/libpath.py -> build/lib/lightgbm
      copying lightgbm/sklearn.py -> build/lib/lightgbm
      running egg_info
      writing lightgbm.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to lightgbm.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to lightgbm.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to lightgbm.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'lightgbm.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'build'
      warning: no files found matching '*.so' under directory 'lightgbm'
      warning: no files found matching '*.so' under directory 'compile'
      warning: no files found matching '*.dll' under directory 'compile/Release'
      warning: no files found matching '*.dll' under directory 'compile/windows/x64/DLL'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'compile/external_libs/compute/.git'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'lightgbm.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      copying lightgbm/VERSION.txt -> build/lib/lightgbm
      installing to build/bdist.macosx-12-arm64/wheel
      running install
      INFO:LightGBM:Starting to compile the library.
      INFO:LightGBM:Starting to compile with CMake.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/private/var/folders/s2/v6j9g8sn213cxwld7zqhy__c0000gn/T/pip-install-wdkadg2j/lightgbm_57587b567aea47d381d9404da623e5b5/setup.py", line 95, in silent_call
          subprocess.check_call(cmd, stderr=log, stdout=log)
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
          retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 345, in call
          with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1845, in _execute_child
          raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cmake'
      
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/s2/v6j9g8sn213cxwld7zqhy__c0000gn/T/pip-install-wdkadg2j/lightgbm_57587b567aea47d381d9404da623e5b5/setup.py", line 334, in <module>
          setup(name='lightgbm',
        File "/Users/alex/iris/external-adapter/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/Users/alex/iris/external-adapter/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 335, in run
          self.run_command('install')
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/s2/v6j9g8sn213cxwld7zqhy__c0000gn/T/pip-install-wdkadg2j/lightgbm_57587b567aea47d381d9404da623e5b5/setup.py", line 248, in run
          compile_cpp(use_mingw=self.mingw, use_gpu=self.gpu, use_cuda=self.cuda, use_mpi=self.mpi,
        File "/private/var/folders/s2/v6j9g8sn213cxwld7zqhy__c0000gn/T/pip-install-wdkadg2j/lightgbm_57587b567aea47d381d9404da623e5b5/setup.py", line 198, in compile_cpp
          silent_call(cmake_cmd, raise_error=True, error_msg='Please install CMake and all required dependencies first')
        File "/private/var/folders/s2/v6j9g8sn213cxwld7zqhy__c0000gn/T/pip-install-wdkadg2j/lightgbm_57587b567aea47d381d9404da623e5b5/setup.py", line 99, in silent_call
          raise Exception("\n".join((error_msg, LOG_NOTICE)))
      Exception: Please install CMake and all required dependencies first
      The full version of error log was saved into /Users/alex/LightGBM_compilation.log
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lightgbm
  Running setup.py clean for lightgbm
Failed to build lightgbm
Installing collected packages: lightgbm
  Running setup.py install for lightgbm ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for lightgbm did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [41 lines of output]
      running install
      /Users/alex/iris/external-adapter/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      INFO:LightGBM:Starting to compile the library.
      INFO:LightGBM:Starting to compile with CMake.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/private/var/folders/s2/v6j9g8sn213cxwld7zqhy__c0000gn/T/pip-install-wdkadg2j/lightgbm_57587b567aea47d381d9404da623e5b5/setup.py", line 95, in silent_call
          subprocess.check_call(cmd, stderr=log, stdout=log)
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
          retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 345, in call
          with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1845, in _execute_child
          raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cmake'
      
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/s2/v6j9g8sn213cxwld7zqhy__c0000gn/T/pip-install-wdkadg2j/lightgbm_57587b567aea47d381d9404da623e5b5/setup.py", line 334, in <module>
          setup(name='lightgbm',
        File "/Users/alex/iris/external-adapter/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/s2/v6j9g8sn213cxwld7zqhy__c0000gn/T/pip-install-wdkadg2j/lightgbm_57587b567aea47d381d9404da623e5b5/setup.py", line 248, in run
          compile_cpp(use_mingw=self.mingw, use_gpu=self.gpu, use_cuda=self.cuda, use_mpi=self.mpi,
        File "/private/var/folders/s2/v6j9g8sn213cxwld7zqhy__c0000gn/T/pip-install-wdkadg2j/lightgbm_57587b567aea47d381d9404da623e5b5/setup.py", line 198, in compile_cpp
          silent_call(cmake_cmd, raise_error=True, error_msg='Please install CMake and all required dependencies first')
        File "/private/var/folders/s2/v6j9g8sn213cxwld7zqhy__c0000gn/T/pip-install-wdkadg2j/lightgbm_57587b567aea47d381d9404da623e5b5/setup.py", line 99, in silent_call
          raise Exception("\n".join((error_msg, LOG_NOTICE)))
      Exception: Please install CMake and all required dependencies first
      The full version of error log was saved into /Users/alex/LightGBM_compilation.log
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lightgbm

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I have attempted to solve this problem by:

1. Installing `wheel` seperately as recommended here: https://pypi.org/project/lightgbm/
2. Install `libomp` using `brew`: https://pypi.org/project/lightgbm/. But I apparently already have it installed.
3. Reinstall `libomp` using `brew` as recommended by brew. No effect.